# How can my Java application be notified when the user clicks on a character in the macOS Character Viewer?

Tags: macos, text, unicode

A native text based application like TextEdit will insert the character when the user clicks on a character in Character Viewer. I would like to do something similar in my Java application, but I have not found any documentation that would explain how an application that is not using an AppKit text view would do this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out, with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62865658/macos-take-emoji-from-characterpalette-revised) and looking at the source of the IDEA IDE. The custom `JComponent` must supply an `InputMethodRequests` that implements the `getTextLocation` method (returning a rectangle in screen coordinates that is used to position the popover). The custom `JComponent` must also respond to the `INPUT_METHOD_TEXT_CHANGED` event, which is generated when the user selects an emoji or symbol. Still to be done is adding code to support actual input methods.